# No module named 'skimage'

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm importing skimage in a python code.

```
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
```

and I get this error

> ***No module named 'skimage'***

Although I've already installed the scikit-image. Can anyone help ?

This is the output of pip freeze

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your code snippets,

Comment: please share a image of your `pip freeze` or `conda list`

Comment: show your code, so that we can help more accurately

Comment: Check you may have multiple version of python installed like: `pip` for version 2x and `pip3` for version 3x.

Comment: It's recommended to use `python3 -m pip install package_name`

Comment: I've edited the question by adding the code and installed packages list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since pip freeze indeed shows scikit-image as installed, I presume that you are launching your script/session using a different *environment* from the one listed by pip. You should make sure that you are in the same environment. Try `python -m pip freeze` and `python my_script.py` from the same terminal to make sure that you are comparing the same environment.

RealPython has a decent guide on Python environments [here](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).

Comment: That was exactly my problem .. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip install scikit-image`.

Also, see the [recommended procedure](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3 you should install the package using `python3 -m pip install package_name` or `pip3 install package_name`

Using the `pip` binary will install the package for `python2` on some systems.